# Copy behavior in composed Swift struct

Tags: swift

```
// definition: Company: { Member { [Activity { times: Int }] }
struct Company {
    var bossId: Int = 0
    var members: [Int: Member] = [:]
    var boss: Member? { 
        get { return members[bossId] }
        set { members[bossId] = newValue }
    }
}

struct Member {
    var name: String
    var activities: [Activity]
}

struct Activity {
    var type: String
    var times: Int
}

// init
var company = Company()
company.members[0] = Member(name: "John",activities: [Activity(type: "Walk", times: 0)])
company.members[1] = Member(name: "Sean", activities: [Activity(type: "Run", times: 0)])
```

I have a computed property in my top structure, `boss` returns one of the members by `id`. When I want to update the properties of some leaf members, compiler complains it needs a setter.  So I add a `members[bossId] = newValue` setter for it. It seems when value is being mutating, it will assign a new updated `Member` to replace original `Member`, because it is `struct` instead of `class`.

Does it cause whole copy of struct `boss: Member` even I just need update one `int` property of member?

Should I worry this redundant copy? Or compiler is smart enough to minimize impact?

```
// use
company.boss?.activities[0].times = 1 
company.boss?.activities[0].times = 2
company.boss?.activities[0].times = 3 // <- Does it cause 3 times whole `Member` copy?
```

Comment: Off topic but why is id a key in a dictionary instead of a property of the `Member` struct ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is just a minimal example, in my project the id is also a property of Member.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Swift structs are extremely cheap to copy - it's just a matter of writing values to a memory location. It's similar to assigning Int values, you don't get a performance penalty if you pass around the value 5.

This of course assumes the struct is not huge, like having hundreds of fields, in which case the actual copy can pose some performance issues, but anyway less than operations that involve heap allocations.

Getting back to your case, your three structs are not big at all:

```swift
print("Company:", MemoryLayout<Company>.size)   // 16
print("Member:", MemoryLayout<Member>.size)     // 24
print("Activity:", MemoryLayout<Activity>.size) // 24
print("Array<Activity>:", MemoryLayout<[Activity]>.size) // 8
```

So, changing properties on one of those structs is a matter of rewriting 8 to 24 bytes, which happens really fast.

So, with the above in mind, let's break down what happens when you write something like

```swift
company.boss?.activities[0].times = 2
```

This is, roughly, what happens under the hood:

1. `activities[0].times = 2` results in `Array` updating the `times` value for the first item in the array
2. the `company.boss?.activities` property is replaced by a new instance of `Array<Activity>`, which means rewriting 8 bytes (the size of the `Array` struct)
3. the `company.boss` property gets replaced with the values after the update from #2, which means a write of 24 bytes
4. finally, the `company` itself is rewritten, 16 more bytes

So, in total, the rewrites count for less than 50 bytes, it could be way less depending on how much the compiler optimizes the memory writes. Even if this happens 3 times, like in your example, is still incredibly fast.

---

P.S. It could be that `activities[0].times = 2` to result in another heap allocation, which would have a bigger performance impact, if the Copy-on-write mechanism enters into play. However this is bound to happen regardless how you structure your structs.